# EndPoint not found in REST service from Android Phone

Tags: c#, android, wcf, rest, post

Ok, I have a WCF Service that keeps me giving a Endpoint not found error, and I can't see why it does... Here's my code.

First, the Interface:

```
 public interface ISightingServiceRest
 {
    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "POST", 
    UriTemplate = "SaveNewSightingRest", 
    ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, 
    RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
    string SaveNewSightingRest(string sighting);
 }
```

Now, the actual method:

```
public string SaveNewSightingRest(string sighting)
{
    string received = sighting;
    return "hola";
}
```

As I'm debugging, all I want is to see the string "hola" in my response, and the sent string in the variable "received".

Now, the webconfig:

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="LiveAndesWCF" connectionString="Data Source=BRUNO-PC\LIVEANDES; 
Initial Catalog=liveandes;Trusted_Connection=Yes;" 
providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
    <add name="LiveAndes" connectionString="Data Source=BRUNO-PC\LIVEANDES; Initial 
Catalog=liveandes;Trusted_Connection=Yes;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
  </connectionStrings>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0"/>
    <membership>
      <providers>
        <clear/>
        <add name="AspNetSqlMembershipProvider" 
          type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider"  
          connectionStringName="LiveAndes" 
          enablePasswordRetrieval="false" enablePasswordReset="true" 
          requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" requiresUniqueEmail="true"      
          maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5" minRequiredPasswordLength="6" 
          minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0" passwordAttemptWindow="10" 
          applicationName="/"/>
      </providers>
    </membership>
  </system.web>
  <appSettings>
    <!--Local-->
    <add key="mainPathDeployWCF" value="http://localhost:61642/"/>
    <add key="mainMachPathDeployWCF" value="\LiveAndesWCF\bin"/>

  </appSettings>

  <system.serviceModel>
    <protocolMapping>
      <add scheme="http" binding="wsHttpBinding" />
    </protocolMapping>
    <services>

      <service name="LiveAndesWCF.SightingServiceRest"
             behaviorConfiguration="MetadataBehavior">
        <endpoint address="" behaviorConfiguration="WebBehavior"
                binding="webHttpBinding"
                contract="LiveAndesWCF.ISightingServiceRest"/>
      </service>

    </services>
    <bindings>
      <webHttpBinding>
        <binding maxReceivedMessageSize="99999999" closeTimeout="00:02:00" 
          openTimeout="00:02:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:02:00">
          <readerQuotas maxArrayLength="76384000" maxStringContentLength="2147483647"/>
        </binding>
      </webHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <behaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="jsonBehavior">
          <enableWebScript/>
        </behavior>
        <behavior name="WebBehavior">
          <webHttp />
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>

          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>

          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
        </behavior>
        <behavior name="MetadataBehavior">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpGetUrl="" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true"/>
  </system.serviceModel>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Finally, the method I'm using from the emulator:

```
private void addNewSighting() throws Exception
{
    String URL = "http://10.0.2.2:61642/SightingServiceRest.svc";

    AlertDialog popup;

    SightingWrapper sighting = new SightingWrapper();

    String xml = createXML(sighting);

    try{
        HttpPost request = new HttpPost(URL + "/SaveNewSightingRest/");

        StringEntity sen = new StringEntity(xml);

        request.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");
        request.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");

        request.setEntity(sen);

        DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(request);

        HttpEntity responseEntity = response.getEntity();

        char[] buffer = new char[(int)responseEntity.getContentLength()];

        InputStream stream = responseEntity.getContent();
        InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader(stream);
        reader.read(buffer);
        stream.close();

        String responseString = new String(buffer);

    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {           

    }

}
```

I receive in the "responseString" the "Endpoint not found" message.

I have no clue where could my error be.

Any help is appreciated.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try removing the trailing slash in the address

```
HttpPost request = new HttpPost(URL + "/SaveNewSightingRest/"); //before
HttpPost request = new HttpPost(URL + "/SaveNewSightingRest"); //after
```